# Gson JsonObject copy value affected others JsonObject instance

Tags: java, gson

I have weird problem with gson (my gson version is 2.3.1)
I have JsonObject instance called jsonObject (JsonObject jsonObject)
jsonObject has value, not empty
And I create another one, JsonObject tempOject = jsonObject;
So, when I try to remove element inside tempObject, lets say,
tempObject.remove("children");

Then that code affected the jsonObject instance.

Here is the code snippet :

```
jsonObject              = element.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement tempElement = element;
        JsonObject tempObject   = jsonObject;
        String tempJson;

        if(tempObject.has("children")){
            tempObject.remove("children");
            tempJson = tempObject.toString();
            tempElement = new JsonParser().parse(tempJson);
        }

        if(nodes.isEmpty()){
            elements = new ArrayList<>();
            nodes.put(iterator, elements);
        }
        if(!nodes.containsKey(iterator)){
            elements = new ArrayList<>();
            nodes.put(iterator, elements);
        }
        nodes.get(iterator).add(tempElement);

        if (jsonObject.has("children")){
            tempNextJson        = jsonObject.get("children").toString();
            tempCurrJson        = jsonObject.toString();

            tempIterator++;
            metaDataProcessor(tempNextJson, tempCurrJson, tempNextJson, tempIterator, maxLevel);
        }
```

I have read the gson JsonObject class, it use deep copy method. That was not supposed to affected the reference since JsonObject using deep value copy, so the returned JsonObject object is the new one.

But why this is happened?

Anyway...there is deepCopy method inside JsonObject class

```
JsonObject deepCopy() {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    Iterator i$ = this.members.entrySet().iterator();

    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        Entry entry = (Entry)i$.next();
        result.add((String)entry.getKey(), ((JsonElement)entry.getValue()).deepCopy());
    }

    return result;
}
```

But thats an abstract method from JsonElement class which implemented on JsonObject, and the attribute not set as public, so I cannot call that method. But I guess that method supposedly called directly when I do instance copy.

How about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By doing `tempOject = jsonObject`, temObject is keeping the same object reference... you will need to do `tempOject = jsonObject.clone()`

Comment: There is no clone() method inside JsonObject, so I cannot do jsonObject.clone()

Comment: If you do not need to use gson, json-io (https://github.com/jdereg/json-io) can be used for cloning Java objects:  `return JsonReader.jsonToJava(JsonWriter.objectToJson(root))`  It is available on Maven Central.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be used to copy any object of any type!
just have to use Gson.

```
public <T> T deepCopy(T object, Class<T> type) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(object, type), type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

in your case you can call it like:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = deepCopy(oldJsonObject, JsonObject.class);
```

Comment: Note: you should not rebuild gson each time deepCopy is called

Comment: Do not miss below solution, that deepCopy() is now a public method of JsonElement. No need for tricks any more.

Answer (score 11):

Starting from version 2.8.2, `deepCopy()` in Gson `JsonElement` is public, so you can now use it to make a deep copy of your JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `tempObject = jsonObject` will not create a second object for you.  All that does is create another reference to your original jsonObject.

What you want to do is something like:

```
JSONObject tempObject = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());
tempObject.remove("children");
```

This will create a *new* JsonObject which is a copy of the original json you had.

---

If you can only use the GSON libraries, there is the JsonObject.deepyCopy() method.  Which was added in r855:  https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/detail?r=855

Using the deepCopy() method it would be

```
JsonObject tempObject = jsonObject.deepCopy();
tempObject.remove("children");
```

Comment: JsonObject constructor has only empty constructor, without takes any parameter on that. So your approach cannot done in JsonObject. I have try that too, but after I look inside the JsonObject class definition, there are no such a constructor which takes parameter

Comment: Do you have access to this API?
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28org.json.JSONObject,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29
GSON is build on top of the JSON libraries so you should still have access to the public JSONObject(JSONObject jo, java.lang.String[] names) constructor.

Comment: if you use JsonObject from Gson, there is no constructor like in JSONObject from json.org. This is different gson parser.

Comment: It looks like they did add a jsonObject.deepCopy() in the gson library in r855.  See here: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/detail?r=855
In case you're using an old version of the GSON lib, you can just copy this method into a helper method and that should get you what you want.

Comment: Ya I have seen that change, but since I use the last version of gson, so I think my gson library newer than that. But I must try.
Btw, what is helper method, sorry I don't know that. Can you give me example how to do that? sorry

Comment: I mean, how can I change my original JsonObject class to that one?
I see the change are only the source codes, not the jar...

Comment: Anyway, I have edited my question, there is deepCopy method inside my original JsonObject class. But thats not working and I cannot call them directly

Comment: deepCopy method is private!, cannot be used out side its scope, you can use Gson to parse the jsonObject to a string and then read the string again using Gson into another object, if anyone needs it I will post a complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Gson developers decided not to expose `deepCopy()`. You could serialize your `JsonElement` this into a string and back, however, I think it's far more efficient to implement deep cloning outside of `JsonObject` instead. Here's my solution to this:

```
@Nonnull
public static JsonObject deepCopy(@Nonnull JsonObject jsonObject) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        result.add(entry.getKey(), deepCopy(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return result;
}

@Nonnull
public static JsonArray deepCopy(@Nonnull JsonArray jsonArray) {
    JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
    for (JsonElement e : jsonArray) {
        result.add(deepCopy(e));
    }
    return result;
}

@Nonnull
public static JsonElement deepCopy(@Nonnull JsonElement jsonElement) {
    if (jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive() || jsonElement.isJsonNull()) {
        return jsonElement;       // these are immutables anyway
    } else if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        return deepCopy(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject());
    } else if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
        return deepCopy(jsonElement.getAsJsonArray());
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported element: " + jsonElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exposed in 2.8.2, per JaakkoK's recent answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the simplest solution for this. Since the deepCopy() method from JsonObject seems didn't work, then I just to make some transformation from JsonObject value to string and then transform to JsonElement with JsonParser().
Then make some new JsonObject from our new JsonObject. It seems more simple instead of create some helper method which is needs to reimplement the deepCopy. If we reimplement the iteration must considered how deep the JsonObject is. Since JsonObject is hashmap (LinkedTreeMap), and the value is JsonElement, so it need to parse recursively through JsonElement.